# What if you wished to take someone else's misery?

Tags: allah

My mom is sick. I love her a lot. I wished for her goodness.One day me,my mom,my dad were sitting and talking Seeing her pain I suddenly wished to take her misery upon my life. But I don't want anything like that. I love my mother a lot. But I don't want to take her misery upon my own life. I wasn't not praying state at that time though and I was napak as well. But still I don't want her misery to go through my life. Will something bad happen to me?...

Answer (score 0):

Bad happens to us only due to our sins. And mostly when we wish to take someone else's pain our intentions are just to free other person of pain. However we should have an attitude and thinking where we perceive our Lord even more great as He is. We should pray to Allah to take pain of that person as He can do and he can vanish the pains with out transferring to someone else.

In your case hopefully those pains are not transferred to you or at least lets assume till now. So still door to Lord is open, pray to Allah that He may keep you safe from all pains.